# sed command how to search and replace git remote branch lists

Tags: git, svn, sed

I have two svn remote branches after migration now how to changes all the remote branch to git local branches using below sed command

```
$ git branch -r
svn-origin/branch-A
svn-origin/branch-B
```

Here how to remove `svn-origin/` to git local branch.

```
$ git branch -r | grep branch | sed 's/svn-origin//'
```

My required output is something like this:

```
$ git branch
branch-A
branch-B
```

Comment: If any of the following answer helped you in your goal please accept/upvote the answer for closure by ticking right sign besides the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use different separation markers, for instance `#`:

```
git branch -r | grep branch | sed 's#svn-origin/##'
```

Now `sed` will replace `svn-origin/` with the empty string. `sed` reads the `s` command, and the next character it considers to be the *separator*. So in case you want to use `/` (or any other character in your expressions), simply use a different separator.

If you want to **remove the leading spaces** as well, you can use:

```
git branch -r | grep branch | sed 's#^\s*svn-origin/##'
```

So with `\s*` to remove the spaces and `^` as anchor point (`^` is not required).

Answer (score 1):

```
git branch -r |awk -F'/' '/branch/{print $NF}'
```

OR

```
git branch -r |grep branch|sed -r 's|(^.*/)(.*)|\2|'
```

Comment: Hi PS, Thanks lot i tried second solution it is worked good :)